# Bootstrap popover html template can't read angular directive

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, popover

I am trying to make bootstrap popover with external HTML file.
the popover is working great with the template, but I encounter a problem:
I can't make the directive work with the template file.
In the template `schools.html` you can see a call to a directive named: `changeColor`. When I am clicking the button the directive doesn't work.

Here is the plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/YAfwK5/preview

Comment: Include relevant code in your question, plz.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your plnkr, see results [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yFepo4T8yxx226lCH9Eh?p=preview).

Relevant changes:

- In the HTML changed `changeColor` to `change-color` to link the directive
- In the directive changed `$('.changeColor')` to `elem()`
- In the directive changed `$('.btm-primary')` to `elem()`

Comment: If the answer is to your satisfaction, please use the checkmark in front of the answer to accept the answer